# How do I execute a function after a two-second hover?

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps

This is my current code

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, `mouseover`, function() { 
  alert('loaded when i hovered');
});
```

but I want the function to be executed if the mouse **is over the element for two seconds**.

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, `mouseover  2000`, function() { 
   alert('loaded after then when i stay mouse 2 sec'); 
 });
```

What do I need to do to make the function execute after a two-second hover?

Comment: Please Replay me with example. thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use a timer. Set it in mouseover, then in the timer  callback do your work; also you need to handle a mouseout event where you stop the timer.

```
var timeoutId = null;
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover',function() { 
   timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function(){
     alert("I did it!");
   }, 2000);
 } );

// Cancel your action if mouse moved out within 2 sec
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout',function() { 
  window.clearTimeout(timeoutId)
});
```

Comment: Useful! In 2024 you can omit "window.".

Answer (score 3):

It would be something like this, using [setTimeout](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAB&url=http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp&ei=ort-UKWaMcquqAHAnoGoBg&usg=AFQjCNE8Eo9hrhgo2ztRqSGffI91oRAGGw&sig2=chFBr4gTX8Z9MwmyrEwALQ)

```
var timer;

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {        
   timer = window.setTimeout(function(){
     alert("Stackoverflow Rocks!!!");
   }, 2000);
 } );

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {        
   window.clearTimeout(timer);
 } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `setTimeout` in the mouseover event. Store the return value somewhere shared (e.g. in a closure).

Call `clearTimeout` in the mouseout event. If that event doesn't fire before the two seconds are up, then the function you pass to `setTimeout` will be called.