# Cytoscape React - How to wait 1 second before starting the hover effect in cytoscape on a node/edge

Tags: reactjs, hover, cytoscape

I'm trying to do a hover effect, when the user hover a node, the other edges/nodes disappear (except the current hover node, and his neighbors, the edges). There is a good example on genemania (https://genemania.org/) when you hover a node. This what I tried to reproduce.

This is how I toggle my classes to my nodes/edges:

```
    function toggleClassHide(cy, elems, ids){
        /*
        * @PARAMS:  - cy: cytoscape canva, dom
        *           - elems: array of object, node/edge
        *           - ids: array of int, id
         */
        elems.forEach(function(item){
            let id = item.data.id;
            if (!ids.includes(id)){
                cy.$("#" + item.data.id).toggleClass("hide");
            }
        })
    }

    function getIdsNeighbours(elem, neighbours){
        var tab = neighbours.map(function(e) {
            return e.data().id;
        })
        tab.push(elem.id());
        return tab;
    }
...
cy.on('mouseover', 'node', function(evt) {
            /*
            * When you hover a node, add hover class to the current, and hide all the other nodes and edges which are not linked with the current node
             */
            // add hover class
            let node = evt.target;
            cy.nodes(node).toggleClass("hover");

            // get the ids of the nodes the neighbours around the node
            let neighboursNode = node.neighborhood('node');
            nodeNeighboursIds = getIdsNeighbours(node, neighboursNode);
            // get the ids of the edges the neighbours around the node
            let neighboursEdge = node.neighborhood('edge');
            edgeNeighboursIds = getIdsNeighbours(node, neighboursEdge)

            toggleClassHide(cy, nodes, nodeNeighboursIds);
            toggleClassHide(cy, edges, edgeNeighboursIds);
        });

        cy.on('mouseout', 'node', function(evt) {
            /*
            * When you are not hover the current node, toggle any classes hide/hover
             */
            let node = evt.target;
            toggleClassHide(cy, nodes, nodeNeighboursIds);
            toggleClassHide(cy, edges, edgeNeighboursIds);
            cy.nodes(node).toggleClass("hover");
        });
```

I've tried to install qtip. But I did not succeed with React.
I've tried setTimeOut. Not the solution (launch many hover effect).

Thanks for your help! sorry for my English

## Update

I finally found an issue. A simple setTimeOut was the solution. This my code if someone needs a similar functionality.

```
var timeoutNode = null;
    cy.on('mouseover', 'node', function(evt){
        /*
        * When you hover a node, add hover class to the current, and hide all the other nodes and edges which are not linked with the current node
         */
        timeoutNode = window.setTimeout(function(){
            let node = evt.target;
            cy.nodes(node).addClass("hover");
            cy.nodes().difference(cy.nodes(node).neighborhood().union(node)).addClass("hide")
            cy.edges().difference(cy.nodes(node).connectedEdges()).addClass("hide")
        }, 700);
    })
    cy.on('mouseout', 'node', function(evt){
        /*
        * When you are not hover the current node, toggle any classes hide/hover
        */
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutNode)
        let node = evt.target;
        cy.nodes().difference(cy.nodes(node).neighborhood().union(node)).removeClass("hide")
        cy.edges().difference(cy.nodes(node).connectedEdges()).removeClass("hide")
        cy.nodes(node).removeClass("hover");
    })
```

Here's the original solution : [How do I execute a function after a two-second hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936103/how-do-i-execute-a-function-after-a-two-second-hover)
Thanks :)